# How do you make a function change the variable put into it in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have been doing `sheet.stopTC(aVal)`

and it seems to go fine, however here:

```
key: "stopTC",
value: function stopTC(z) {

  if (z == true) {
    z = false;
    console.log("cache started");
  } else {
    z = true;
    console.log("cache stopped");
  }
  return z;
}

//globals
aVal = false
```

the variable is globally set to `false` but when it comes back the `aVal` stays `false` instead of changing to true`.

Sorry I'm new to programming and can't get my head around it.

Comment: If you pass in a variable in a function and *reassign it*, you are not changing the variable outside the function. JavaScript is a pass by value language, so you cannot manipulate what the variable outside the function is, unless you address it directly, e.g., if you do `aVal = true` inside the function, and `aVal` is visible, then it will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `aVal = sheet.stopTC(aVal)` then it will became `true`